# Back button deleting all my textviews

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int counter = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("key2", 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            layout.addView(createToDo(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(Integer.toString(counter), "")), counter);
        }
    }
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.todoMain);
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    textList = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("key");
    for (String t: textList) {
        todoList.add(createToDo(t));
        layout.addView(createToDo(t));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putStringArrayList("key", textList);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    int counter = 0;
    for (String t: textList) {
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(Integer.toString(counter), t);
        counter++;
    }
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().commit();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSettings2 = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferencesSettings2.edit();
    editor2.putInt("key2", counter);
    editor2.commit();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.todoMain);
    int counter = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("key2", 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        layout.addView(createToDo(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(Integer.toString(i), "")), i);
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    int counter = 0;
    for (String t: textList) {
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(Integer.toString(counter), t);
        counter++;
    }
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().commit();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSettings2 = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferencesSettings2.edit();
    editor2.putInt("key2", counter);
    editor2.commit();
}
```

So when I press the back button on my android device or exit the app, it seems to always reset the app and removes all the text views. How do I save my textviews, so they will show up again when pressing back or exiting the app? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you committing the SharedPreferences after updating it?

Take a look at the example below.

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSettings = context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferencesSettings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferencesSettings.edit();

    editor.putBoolean("showRedColor", true);

    editor.commit();
```

Try modifying the methods below.

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    int counter = 0;
    //get an editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    for (String t: textList) {
        //set key values
        editor1.putString(Integer.toString(counter), t).commit();
        counter++;
    }
    //save changes
    editor1.commit();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSettings2 = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferencesSettings2.edit();
    editor2.putInt("key2", counter);
    editor2.commit();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    int counter = 0;
    //get an editor
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
    for (String t: textList) {
        //set key values
        editor1.putString(Integer.toString(counter), t).commit();
        counter++;
    }
    //save changes
    editor1.commit();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesSettings2 = this.getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE2", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferencesSettings2.edit();
    editor2.putInt("key2", counter);
    editor2.commit();
}
```

In your example, you are not saving in the correct editor.

```
for (String t: textList) {
    //Get editor, set the key, but you are not committing the changes, so they are lost
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(Integer.toString(counter), t);
    counter++;
}
//Get a new editor and you are committing, but you haven't edit any of the key value, so you are not commint any changes
getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().commit();
```

Comment: I added in the commits, and it still seems to not work.

Comment: I have updated my answer, try updating the onPause method and OnDestroy

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling commit() on the SharedPreferences editor, so nothing is being saved.

Edit: Also if you are targeting above Lollipop, you can consider using [PersistableBundles](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/PersistableBundle.html) for save and retrieve the state after reopening the app.